# Loading My.Settings in other solution

Tags: vb.net

I need to load My.settings from the first Solution into the Second.

In the first project I have a helper class for getting the Settings.

```
Public Class format
    Public NotInheritable Class Helper
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Shared Function getAppSetting() As String
            Dim returnValue As Object = My.Settings.format
            If returnValue Is Nothing Then
                Return String.Empty
            Else
                Return returnValue.ToString
            End If
        End Function

        Public Shared Function getAppSettingTheme() As String
            Dim returnValue_theme As Object = My.Settings.theme_selected
            If returnValue_theme Is Nothing Then
                Return String.Empty
            Else
                Return returnValue_theme.ToString
            End If
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

This class I have implemented in the other Solutions (Even addiction I have a set)

In other Solutions I have the code for getting the Settings.

```
Imports MyProject.format.Helper
MsgBox(getAppSettingTheme())
```

But in the MsgBox I see Default Settings (Unchanged) While in the first solution displays the user-changed settings.

My.Settings I have saved [My.settings.save]

Comment: Do you want an easy answer or a complicated one ?

Comment: I'll do what I have to. So you can feel free to write.

Comment: i am posting an answer ...

Comment: Look into [_XML Serialization_](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292726/Serialization-Part-III-XML-Serialization) instead. That way you can give your settings the structure you want _and_ read them from any project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to do this in a complicated way,what you have to do is,make classes in the first project to read `My.Settings`,then reference the project in the other project and use it...

However,i'll rather describe an easier way(tho the above one is not that hard) to achieve your goal.

Firstly,i believe that you are using `My.Settings` to store some data,right ?If so,you can simply save the data to a text file and read it from anywhere you want.This will save plenty of your code and make it tidy :)

As you seem to be a beginner,i would try to keep it as simple as possible and explain in the simplest words...

Now,let's assume,you have 4 `My.Settings` entries as follows :

**UserName**

**Password**

**Phone**

**Age**

Instead of writing this data in `My.Settings`,write it to a text file.Let's assume a user inputs relevant data and it looks somewhat like this :

**Zack Rayan**

**1212121**

**+090990809809**

**20**

To write a text file, you can simply use `File.WriteAllText` but as we see that here,our data is in multiline,we can make use of the following :

`FIle.WriteAllLines`

`File.AppendText`

Well,let's use `File.AppendText` method(you can use the below code with `WriteAllText` as well :)) :

```
   File.AppendText("C:\test.mycustomExtension" , "Zack Rayan" + Environment.NewLine + "1212121" + Environment.NewLine + "+090990809809" + Environment.NewLine + "20")
```

This will write a text file for you containing the given data in separate lines as well as you will have your own custom extension for the file :)

Now,how to use it ?

Simple :

```
  Dim ReadFile as New List(Of String)(File.ReadAllLines("C:\Test.mycustomextension"))
```

Now,let's assume,when you were using `My.Settings`, you used some codes like this :

```
   If My.Settings.UserName = "Zack" Then
   ......
```

Scroll up and look closely.**UserName** was your first entry in `My.Settings` and when we wrote the text file,**ZACK RAYAN-the assumed username was also written in the first line**

A few lines above, i created a list which reads the text file.It needs no saying that it will read(and store) the first line first and then move on gradually. So,where you used :

```
 If My.Settings.UserName = "Zack" Then
```

u should now use :

```
 If ReadFile(0) = "Zack" Then
```

I hope this helps to enrich your knowledge :)

Comment: This idea to me, too attacked, but I don't want to rewrite the whole project. So it looks like that's what just I'll do. Thanks.

Comment: you don't like the answer ? i can post the complicated way which includes `My.Settings` , u want it ?